# How to set Mail module's SSL/TLS version manually

Tags: ruby, email, ssl, jruby, jruby-openssl

I am working on fixing a SSL-related bug with the Ruby Mail module in JRuby. This Github issue explains (and provides a monkey patch to) this [bug](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/3360#issuecomment-224403617).

The gist of the bug is that sometime after JRuby-1.7.19, a change was introduced that changes the Net::SMTP behavior with respect with MRI. In order to fix this issue, we must use the following TLS version `TLSv1_2_client` for `OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext` in order to send mail through SSL/TLS.

The person that opened an issue suggested the following monkey patch for the Mail module:

```
require 'net/smtp'

class << Net::SMTP
  remove_method :default_ssl_context # if defined?(Net::SMTP.default_ssl_context)
end

module Net
  class SMTP
    def SMTP.default_ssl_context
      OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new('TLSv1_2_client')
    end
  end
end
```

I tried this, and it does fix the `Algorithm NONE` problem I had by monkey patching SSLContext to use `TLSv1_2_client`, but I am not liking this solution at all because it's:

1. a monkey patch.
2. it's applying a giant bandaid over the core issue, which is an incorrect TLS version being supplied.

The solution I came up with for my app is that I simply have a dropdown populated by values in `OpenSSL::SSL::SSLCOntext::METHODS`. The output to `METHODS` is:

```
0> OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::METHODS
=> [:TLSv1, :TLSv1_server, :TLSv1_client, :SSLv3, :SSLv3_server, :SSLv3_client, :SSLv23, :SSLv23_server, :SSLv23_client, :TLS, :TLSv1_1_server, :TLSv1_1_client, :TLSv1_1, :TLSv1_2, :TLSv1_2_server, :TLSv1_2_client]
```

Right now I intend to fork the Ruby Mail module, and modify the `smtp.rb` [file](https://github.com/mikel/mail/blob/120f0b48c32fdab0fe659ff5c2fc15d96a2309ad/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb#L135) to allow myself to manually set the SSL version.

I am okay with having to fork the Ruby Mail module and make the changes myself.

I tried the following:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::DEFAULT_PARAMS[:ssl_version] = :TLSv1_2_client
```

which did indeed set the default SSL version, but did not fix my issue.

How can I manually set the SSL version without relying on a monkey patch like the above example?